# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1 : NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, nullpointerexception, hibernate-mapping, dialect

I am having Null Pointer Exception while using the following code.

```
 List<Object> = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQueryString)
                 .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Target.class)).list();
```

I have seen this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386648/non-managed-entity-in-hibernate, But it is not useful for me, Because the query result does not have any null values. So i unable to find what is wrong with my code. Can anyone solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the query: sqlQueryString

Comment: @ViralPatel I have mailed you the SQL QUERY to viralpatel.net@gmail.com. Bcz it is very important to my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.addScalar("fieldName", requiredDatatype) method will fix this problem. The following code will explain to you.

```
List<Object> = getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQueryString)
             .addScalar("field_1", Hibernate.INTEGER).addScalar("field_2", Hibernate.INTEGER) .........addScalar("field_n", Hibernate.INTEGER)
             .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Target.class)).list();
```